# which of the following are true out of the four statements?

Tags: functions

let $p(x)= x^n+\sum\limits_{i=0}^\mathbb{n-1}a_k x^k$ and $q(x)= x^n+\sum\limits_{i=0}^\mathbb{n-1}b_k x^k$

be two polynomials with real coefficients such that $n\geqslant 4$ is even and $a_{n-1} $$\lt b_{n-1}$.

let $f(x)$ be a function such that $p(x)\leqslant f(x) \leqslant q(x)$ for all x in $R$.

a) $f(x)$ is a bounded function on $R$

b) $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $R$

c) there exist $x_0$ in $R$ such that $f(x_0)=0$

d) $f(x)$ is continuous at least at one point $x_0$ in $R$.

i know answers is d only but how to prove?

also i want counter examples for others? plz tell me

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading, but it looks like $p(0)=0=q(0)$, no?  Neither has a non-zero constant term.  If I am right about that then $p(0)≤f(0)≤q(0)$ would then mean that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Since $p$ and $q$ are continuous and $p(x)\le f(x)\le q(x)$, any point $x_0$ such that $p(x_0)=q(x_0)$ is a good candidate.

Comment: yes you are right. i have edited my statement

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
The difference of polynomials p and q is a polynomial with odd degree. So it has a root. Now Squeeze theorem or its modification would be useful for proving your statement.

Comment: The difference of those polynomials needs not be odd. For instance, nowhere it states that $a_0=b_0$.

Comment: It says that there is strict inequality between coefficients.

Comment: Odd function $=$ a function such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Polynomial of odd degree $=$ a polynomial of odd degree.

Comment: Yeah, I meant polynomial of odd degree. I will fix it now. Thanks

Comment: how to prove others?

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ and $q$ are continuous and $p(x)\le f(x)\le q(x)$, any point $x_0$ such that $p(x_0)=q(x_0)$ is a good candidate.

Now, do the condition $a_{n-1}\ne b_{n-1}$ and the fact that $p,q$ are monic polynomials of (identical) even degree say anything about $\deg(p-q)$?

Comment: but how we can say $p(x_0)=q(x_0)$ at any point

Comment: Is there a special class of polynomials that are always guaranteed to have a zero in $\Bbb R$, no matter their coefficients?

Comment: i donot know about that

Comment: yes odd degree polynomials

Comment: got your point..

Comment: how to prove others are false?

Comment: The other three need not be true. You can produce counter-examples with an apprpopriate choice of polynomials and $f$.